# Docker: Best practices for installing dependencies - Dockerfile or ENTRYPOINT?

Tags: docker

Being relatively new to Docker development, I've seen a few different ways that apps and dependencies are installed.

For example, in the official Wordpress image, the WP source is downloaded in the Dockerfile and extracted into /usr/src and then this is installed to /var/www/html in the entrypoint script.

Other images download and install the source in the Dockerfile, meaning the entrypoint just deals with config issues.

Either way the source scripts have to be updated if a new version of the source is available, so one way versus the other doesn't seem to make updating for a new version any more efficient.

What are the pros and cons of each approach? Is one recommended over the other for any specific sorts of setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should install application code and dependencies exclusively in the Dockerfile.  The image entrypoint should never download or install anything.

This approach is simpler (you often don't need an `ENTRYPOINT` line at all) and more reproducible.  You might run across some setups that run commands like `npm install` in their entrypoint script; this work will be repeated every time the container runs, and the container won't start up if the network is unreachable.  Installing dependencies in the Dockerfile only happens once (and generally can be cached across image rebuilds) and makes the image self-contained.

The [Docker Hub `wordpress` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) is unusual in that the underlying Wordpress libraries, the custom PHP application, and the application data are all stored in the same directory tree, and it's typical to use a volume mount for that application tree.  [Its entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/8215003254de4bf0a8ddd717c3c393e778b872ce/php7.4/fpm/docker-entrypoint.sh#L48) looks for a `wp-includes/index.php` file *inside the application source tree*, and if it's not there it copies it in.  That's a particular complex entrypoint script.

A generally useful pattern is to keep an application's data somewhere separate from the application source tree.  If you're installing a framework, install it as a library using the host application's ordinary dependency system (for example, list it in a Node `package.json` file rather than trying to include it in a base image).  This is good practice in general; in Docker it specifically lets you mount a volume on the data directory and not disturb the application.

For a typical Node application, for example, you might install the application and its dependencies in a Dockerfile, and not have an `ENTRYPOINT` declared at all:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install

# Install everything else
COPY . ./

# Point at some other data directory
RUN mkdir /data
ENV DATA_DIR=/data
# Application code can look at process.env.DATA_DIR

# Usual application metadata
EXPOSE 3000
CMD yarn start
```

...and then run this with a volume mounted for the data directory, leaving the application code intact:

```
docker build -t my-image .
docker volume create my-data
docker run -p 3000:3000 -d -v my-data:/data my-image
```

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful explanation.